# Why is curl, but not wget, having trust issues with software.download.prss.microsoft.com?

Tags: curl, wget, ssl, certificates

The following URL redirects to a microsoft.com subdomain: https://tb.rg-adguard.net/dl.php?go=3dd1ce66
Namely to `https://software.download.prss.microsoft.com/db/Win10_20H2_v2_EnglishInternational_x64.iso?t=...` (`...` being a random token)

I was able to get the final redirect URL by running:

```
curl -LsI -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} "https://tb.rg-adguard.net/dl.php?go=7e583fea
```

But no matter if I run `wget https://tb.rg-adguard.net/dl.php?go=3dd1ce66` or `wget https://software.download.prss.microsoft.com/db/Win10_20H2_v2_EnglishInternational_x64.iso?t=...................`

I always get certificate errors that I don't get when downloading the file using Firefox.

```
wget https://software.download.prss.microsoft.com/db/Win10_20H2_v2_EnglishInternational_x64.iso\?t\=...................
--2022-04-12 14:57:29--  https://software.download.prss.microsoft.com/db/Win10_20H2_v2_EnglishInternational_x64.iso?t=..........................
Resolving software.download.prss.microsoft.com (software.download.prss.microsoft.com)... 152.199.21.175, 2606:2800:233:1cb7:261b:1f9c:2074:3c
Connecting to software.download.prss.microsoft.com (software.download.prss.microsoft.com)|152.199.21.175|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘software.download.prss.microsoft.com’ is not trusted.
```

Why is the behavior not consistent across different applications (Firefox vs wget). Is there actually reason not to trust that certificate (and if so why is Firefox not catching that) or is wget at fault?

I'm using Fedora 35 x64 with Wget 1.21.2 and Firefox 98.0.

Comment: Nothing at fault - `wget` is using Fedora's certificates (from the `ca-certificates` package), while Firefox uses it's own trust-store.

Comment: Huh, okay thanks for the information. But why would ca-certificates classify it as not-trustworthy?

Comment: Having checked my system (Debian, not Fedora), I find that the microsoft.com URL works for `curl` and `wget`.  Have you installed the `ca-certificates` package?

Comment: Yes, I do and I have tested it on Fedora 34 and Fedora 35 now. I can only download that file using `wget --no-check-certificate ...` which seems like a security risk. :/

Comment: What does `curl -v` say about these?

Comment: @muru Now that I tested it again, I realize that it's only wget that is having issues. With curl I can actually download the file just fine.

Comment: I've just fired up a quick LXC container with Fedora 35 and am seeing the same as you.  `curl` works, but `wget` fails.  I can't even get `wget` to work with the `--ca-certificate={file}` option and a copy of the Digicert Global Root G2 certificate.  This seems a Fedora `wget` issue.

Comment: A little more digging shows that `gnutls-cli software.download.prss.microsoft.com` works on Debian, but fails on Fedora. `wget` uses gnutls for TLS...

Comment: We saw similar weirdness when letsencrypt root ca expired.  The dual chain certificate with one expired CA caused some incompatibility https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/ no idea if this is related.  To begin tracing what's happening you should use OpenSSL commandline to download the certificate chain sent by Microsoft servers. Then you can begin to analyse precisely what certificate chain is invalid.

Comment: @garethTheRed would you mind mentioning which debian / gnutls version you tried.  I think versions will be very important here.

Comment: I used `gnutls` v3.7.1 on Debian 11.  Fedora 35 uses v3.7.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What's broken

It looks like you've tripped up on this known issue: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6830 The last comment there reads:

> Update from the OneOCSP side: Due to a new CAB forum requirement, OneOCSP will switch the algorithm to SHA-256 by 2022-5-31.

According to that issue, `wget` (GnuTLS) is refusing to accept a Microsoft certificate because it has an OCSP URL `URI:http://oneocsp.microsoft.com/ocsp` and oneocsp.microsoft.com is signing its responses with SHA1.  **[SHA1 is depreciated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) and strongly discouraged for use in signatures.**

Arguably wget is doing the right thing by protecting your security.  SHA1 has been considered insecure for some years and using it to sign certificates has not been supported for a few years now.

It's actually quite surprising this hasn't been spotted and fixed sooner; but then I guess OCSP is much less visible to users than x509 certificates themselves.

### Why is this a problem?

[OCSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) solves the problem of revoking certificates before they expire. Certificates can contain an OCSP URL pointing to a server. Clients will read this and ask that server to verify the certificate is still valid and has not been revoked.

The server signs a response to say the certificate is valid and this response expires very quickly (seconds or minutes).  So even when the certificate itself is valid, the OCSP server still needs to be there to confirm it.

But Microsoft's OCSP server is not behaving well...

Digital signatures actually sign a digital fingerprint for the document and SHA1 was previously used to create the fingerprint.  But people have discovered a way to make a new document that matches an existing SHA1 fingerprint so they can fake a document that looks like it matches an existing signature!

So GNUTLS is refusing to trust some Microsoft certificates, because it refuses to trust SHA1 signed responses from Microsoft's OCSP server. Thus it can't be sure whether the certificate itself has been revoked or not.

### Showing my working...

I was able to confirm the certificate's OCSP URL with openssl.  First by fetching the certificates:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername software.download.prss.microsoft.com -connect software.download.prss.microsoft.com:443 </dev/null
```

Then copy-pasting the certificates into files and reading them with with:

```
openssl x509 -in <filename> -text
```

---

In case you're curious how google led me to hat issue:

I ran `wget` with a gnutls debug option enabled:

```bsh
GNUTLS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 wget --verbose https://tb.rg-adguard.net/dl.php?go=3dd1ce66
```

This gives a *really* long debug output with this at the end:

```
gnutls[2]: looking for key purpose '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1', but have '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4'
ERROR: The certificate of ‘software.download.prss.microsoft.com’ is not trusted.
```

While this error is misleading it gave me a little more to go on with google.

Comment: Okay thank you, so in the last comment of that GitHub issue it says "Update from the OneOCSP side: Due to a new CAB forum requirement, OneOCSP will switch the algorithm to SHA-256 by 2022-5-31." Does that mean this error will be gone then?

Comment: @Forivin yes.  Obviously I can't speak for whether or not they will live up to the promise, but I would expect it just to go away some time "soon".

Comment: Okay, thank you, that's good to know. I wasn't sure because in that issue they were talking about a different domain, but I guess it all goes back to the same root cause then.

Comment: @Forivin Yes the domain is different, although the OCSP URL is the same on both certificates: http://oneocsp.microsoft.com/ocsp This is the one that's broken and needs fixing :D

Comment: It's finally fixed, as they promised. Thanks again. :)